# How to override 'cxTranslate' pipe

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Is it possible to override 'cxTranslate' pipe and add some custome behaviour for it?
Can somebody guide how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it shouldn't be a big problem to do so.
Create your own Pipe, f.e.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'customTranslate' })
export class CustomTranslatePipe extends TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(
    protected service: TranslationService,
    protected cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    super(service, cd)
  }
  transform(input: Translatable | string, options: TranslatableParams = {}): string {
    // Your custom implementation goes here
    return this.translatedValue;
  }
}
```

create your own module, that includes your pipe, f.e.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [CustomTranslatePipe],
  exports: [CustomTranslatePipe],
})
export class CustomTranslatePipeModule {}
```

import your module and use your `customTranslate` instead of `cxTranslate` in your templates